# Creating Conky text variables with zero padding?

Tags: conky

I've got a strange issue with my Conky setup:

[image]

What I'm looking to get rid of/fix is the fact that my CPU percentages (using `${cpu cpuX}`) won't seem to pad properly. I'd like all values to be aligned vertically so that statuses never wiggle. Here's excerpts from my conky file:

```
# ...
pad_percents 3
# ...
${cpubar cpu1 6,135}$alignr${...}${cpu cpu1}%
```

How can I right align and pad CPU percentage values so they stop throwing off my layout? The equivalent printf would be `%3.0f` so that values will appear like this:

```
$ "%3.0f" % (1,) 
'  1'
$ "%3.0f" % (13,)
' 13'
$ "%3.0f" % (100,)
'100'
```

How can I make this happen in Conky for my CPU percentage?

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/questions/178179/modify-conky-to-handle-variable-length-values

Comment: Thanks, I wrote a Lua printf function which takes a format string and a value, works great! Only thing now is to set a monospace fonnt so we never see a wiggle due to difference in character widths.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A solution provided by @jasonwryan above:

1. Create a Lua script for Conky to use. I created mine in a folder I made in `~/.config/conky/scripts`, but you can create yours wherever you'd like:

   ```
   $ mkdir -p ~/.config/conky/scripts/
   $ vim ~/.config/conky/scripts/conky_lua_scripts.lua
   ```
2. Fill the file with the following Lua function:

   ```
   function conky_format( format, number )
       return string.format( format, conky_parse( number ) )
   end
   ```
3. Import your Lua script file into your Conky configuration file using the `lua_load` directive

   ```
   # ...
   lua_load ~/.config/conky/scripts/conky_lua_scripts.lua

   TEXT
   # ...
   ```
4. Whenever you'd like to format a value, call the `format` function we defined earlier. Note that though we named it `conky_format`, we access it as `format` using the `lua_parse` variable:

   ```
   # ...
   lua_load ~/.config/conky/scripts/conky_lua_scripts.lua

   TEXT
   # ...
   ${lua_parse format %3.0f ${cpu cpu1}}%
   ```

This nice script allows you to call into Lua formatting engine with any value and format string. The output now looks as expected:

[image: awesome]

If you're familiar with `printf`, you can use the utility to do other awesome formatting hacks.

Comment: conky: Syntax error (/home/jhartley/.config/conky/conky.conf:22: '=' expected near '~') while reading config file.

Answer (score 3):

Almost same effect can be achieved also without lua script by using conditions:

```
${if_match ${cpu cpu1} < 10}${offset 10}${cpu cpu1}%
```

Your code would be something similar to:

```
${cpubar cpu1 6,135}$alignr${...}${if_match ${cpu cpu1} < 10}${offset 10}${endif}${cpu cpu1}%
```

Note: Offset value (in above case 10) needs to be tweaked according to used font.

More complete example can also use more conditions:

```
${cpubar cpu1 6,135}$alignr${...}${if_match ${cpu cpu1} < 10}${offset 20}${else}${if_match ${cpu cpu1} < 100}${offset 10}${endif}${cpu cpu1}%
```

Comment: An alternative to the 'offset' is to have 'if_match' simply output a zero or a space, using something like `${if_match ${cpu cpu0}<10}0${endif}${cpu cpu0}%`