# Conky - string formatting

Tags: bash, awk, c, conky, lua

I have conky the record:

```
${color lightblue} Down: ${downspeed wlan0} Up: ${upspeed wlan0}
```

Conky prints link speed, but the text moves:

```
Down: OB  Up: OB 
Down: 60B  Up: 60B
Down: 148B  Up: 148B
Down: 1KiB  Up: 1KiB
Down: 1.8KiB  Up: 1.8KiB
Down: 1.08KiB  Up: 1.08KiB
Down: 31.8KiB  Up: 31.8KiB
```

Based on this topic [Creating Conky text variables with zero padding?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57789/creating-conky-text-variables-with-zero-padding) I tried to format the output, but the text still moves.

```
${color lightblue} Down: ${lua_parse format %7s ${downspeed wlan0}} Up: ${lua_parse format %7s ${upspeed wlan0}}
```

I want the printed output conky:

```
Down:      0B  Up:      0B
Down:     60B  Up:     60B
Down:    148B  Up:    148B
Down:    1KiB  Up:    1KiB
Down:  1.8KiB  Up:  1.8KiB
Down: 1.08KiB  Up: 1.08KiB
Down: 31.8KiB  Up: 31.8KiB
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using `goto` as referenced here : http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html

You could do something like:

```
${color lightblue} Down: ${lua_parse format %7s ${downspeed wlan0}}${goto 100} Up: ${lua_parse format %7s ${upspeed wlan0}}
```

and just change the `${goto 100}` to a number that better matches your formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Conky places a space between the number and the unit. Hence the longest possible string is 8, not 7, characters long.

Hence, using the `conky_format` function from [Creating Conky text variables with zero padding?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57824/), the following code should work:

```
${color lightblue} Down: ${lua format %8s ${downspeed wlan0}} Up: ${lua format %8s ${upspeed wlan0}}
```

Note, you do not need the `lua_parse` variable, since the `conky_format` function already uses the `conky_parse` function.