# Conky text padding with dzen2

Tags: xmonad, conky

I have the exact same issue as [Creating Conky text variables with zero padding?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57789/creating-conky-text-variables-with-zero-padding) for displaying network speed.
Except that I'm piping conky to **dzen2**. It seems lua_parse is not working within that setup.

I've tried :

1. Formatting the string directly :  `${lua_parse format %2s ${downspeed re0}}`
2. Using `goto` : `${downspeed re0}${goto 100}`
3. Setting a custom function in `~/.xmonad/conky_lua_script.lua`  :

```
function conky_format( format, number )
    return string.format( format, conky_parse( number ) )
end
```

Then in conkyrc:

```
lua_load = "~/.xmonad/conky_lua_script.lua"

conky.text = [[ 
 ${lua_parse format %5.0f ${downspeed re0}}% 
]];
```

Minimal working example :

```
conky.config = {
    background = true,
    out_to_console = true,
    out_to_x = false,
    update_interval = 1.0,
    use_spacer = 'none',
    use_xft = true
};


conky.text = [[
${downspeed re0}
]];
```

Run it with `conky | dzen2` .

**Edit**
The following works :

```
conky.config = {
    lua_load = "~/.xmonad/conky_lua_script.lua"
    ....
};

conky.text = [[
${lua format %7s ${downspeed re0}}
]];
```

Comment: Are you using a monospaced font in dzen2? Otherwise the text is bound to move. Are you using `format_human_readable = false,` with `use_spacer = 'left',` in conky?

Comment: I was setting `DejaVu Sans Mono` in conky but it seems like it did nothing.
With a monospace font in dzen instead and`user_spacer = 'left'` in conky, it's much better. Text still moves when switching units though. I did not set `format_human_readable = false`, as it made speeds hard to read. So the best solution for now is to used `downspeedf` instead of `downspeed` for fixed text. I still prefer the output of `downspeed` though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize this is a pretty stale question, but I recently ran into the same problem and this was high on the search results. Since I was able to uncover the answer, I figured I'd post it for the sake of anyone else that runs into this problem.

The `lua_load = ...` must be in your `conky.config` table (and not at the top level of the file the way it was in the old config syntax). Something like this:

```
conky.config = {
    lua_load = 'path_to_script.lua',
    ...
};
```

Odd that even with debug enabled through `-DD` conky doesn't complain about the misplaced line.